# Coloring Continuous set of Pixels

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a program written in python using OpenCV in which I am trying to color a group of pixels. The condition is that if there is more than 1000 continuous pixels, then all those 1000 pixels must get colored with a different color, and for this example, that color is red.

The code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

print("Package Imported")

coordinate = x, y = 150, 69
imgColor = cv2.imread(r"D:\Downloads\residence-g1678df24f_1280.jpg")
img = cv2.imread(
    r"D:\Downloads\residence-g1678df24f_1280.jpg", 0)
res, img2 = cv2.threshold(img, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

l = len(img2)
w = len(img2[0])
print(l, w)
count = 1

y=0
x=0
sX=0
sY=0
for x in range(0,l):
    imgColor[0,x]=(0,0,255)
    for y in range(0,w):

        if img2[x,y]==255:
            count=count+1
        else:
            count=1
            sX = x
            sY = y
            print(img2[x,y],x,y)

        if count > 1000:
            print("Coloring from ", sX, sY, "to ", x, y)
            for i in range(sX, x):
                for j in range(sY, y):
                    imgColor[i, j] = (0, 0, 255)
                    count=1

cv2.imshow("GrayScale Image", img)
cv2.imshow("Photo", img2)
cv2.imshow("Color Image", imgColor)
cv2.imwrite("D:/VS Projects/openCVTEST/ColoredImage.jpg", imgColor)
cv2.imwrite("D:/VS Projects/openCVTEST/ThresholdImage.jpg", img2)
cv2.imwrite("D:/VS Projects/openCVTEST/GrayScaleImage.jpg",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Basically, I first `threshold` the image and then use an `if` operator to check id the current pixel is white. If the pixel is white, then the variable `count` is incremented. If not, then `count` is reset back to 0 and `sX` and `sY` are marked as the starting coordinates. Once `count` exceeds 1000, then another `for` loop runs, coloring `imgColor` for `(sX,sY)` to the current pixel `(x,y)`.

However, the results that I am getting are like this:

ImgColor:

[image]

img2 (Threshold):

[image]

img (Grayscale):
[image]

Ideally, shouldn't a lot more white space (such as the whitespace on the left of the house) be colored red as well? Since the `thresholded` image has only `255` or `0`, a lot more of the `255` should also be colored `red`. Is my logic itself wrong, or am I missing something? I changed the min count `(count > 100)` to 100, but even that is producing similar results.

Comment: for y in range(0,w)
and

    if count > 1000:

it means your code just count same rgb in width .

Comment: @yangjiang, I am sorry, I did not understand. What do u mean by counting same rgb in width ?

Comment: Use a 2x1 and a 1x2 filter with entries [-1,1]. To find regions of identical value. When filter result is 0, the pixel has the same value as the neighbor, so finding contours in the mask filterResult==0 will give you those regions. You can then use inRange for a specific intensity value to get the border correctly.

Comment: Thank you @Micka. I am kinda new to OpenCV so I am not able to understand what you mean by a 2x1 and a 1x2 filter. Could you please provide a snippet, so that I can Google and understand further ?

Comment: it is similar to a 3x3 sobel filter: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator maybe you are able to google that one and understand the idea better. The general idea is to identify "change" on a per pixel leven, to then find pixel cluster without change ( = same color value)

Comment: if you are only interested in finding continuous regions of a single specified value (e.g. only exactly white) you dont need these filters at all, you can just use cv2.inRange with that specific value.

Comment: @Micka, Thank you so much for your advice. I will check both of them out

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this effect, you can continue to look at my following example code

[image]

```
import cv2

# read the picture
img_color = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\SY\Desktop\test\A.jpg", 1)
img_gray = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\SY\Desktop\test\A.jpg", 0)
# get img_hight and img_width
img_hight = len(img_color)
img_width = len(img_color[0])

# use the key to change the result
threshold_key = 150
img_gray = cv2.threshold(img_gray, threshold_key, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

color_one = (0,0,255)
for hight in range(0, img_hight):
    flag_width = 0
    for width in range(0, img_width):
        if img_gray[hight, width] == 0:  
            if width - flag_width  > 200 :
                for w in range(flag_width, width):
                    img_color[hight, w] = color_one
            flag_width = width
        
        # if the whole line is whithe
        if (width == img_width-1) and (flag_width == 0) :
            for w in range(width+1): 
                img_color[hight, w] = color_one
cv2.imwrite("A.bmp", img_color)
```